# How to convert string to binary in Teradata?

Tags: teradata

I don't find any functions to convert string to binary in Teradata Database manual-SQL Reference -Functions and Operators. 
Cast string to byte does not work too.

SELECT C1, C2 FROM table WHERE C1 < (cast( ('QREPI.\k'||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'
XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'
..')  as byte(24)) ));
 *** Failure 3532 Conversion between BYTE data and other types is illegal.
                Statement# 1, Info =0

Anybody knows if Teradata provides a way for the conversion?

Any comments are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is a literal, you can get a binary equivalent of your string like this:

```
SELECT C1, C2 FROM table
WHERE C1 < '51524550492e5c6b000000000000000000000000'xb
```

Otherwise, for data that is stored in your tables in hex it could be done within Teradata by writing a new UDF. Or you could export it to a file, transform it with a program, and load it back.

Answer (score 0):

According to [their blog](http://readvitamin.com/2007/08/03/%E2%80%98implicit%E2%80%99-and-%E2%80%98explicit%E2%80%99-casting-in-teradata/) you should be able to do it with implicit casting (but not explicit).  I take that to mean something like:

```
SELECT C1, C2 
  FROM table 
  WHERE C1 < ('QREPI.\k'||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||
     '00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||' ..');
```

Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But　it does not work.
SELECT C1, C2 FROM table 
  WHERE C1 < ('QREPI.\k'||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||
     '00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||'00'XC||' ..');

 *** Failure 3640 Comparing BYTE data in column C1 with other types is
 illegal.

Comment: BTW, what's the blog you see? Thanks!

Comment: @freevictor -- click on the link (the words "their blog" in my answer) and it will take you right there.

Comment: Hi Mark, Sorry I didn't note the link. Thanks for the warm heart help.